# How do I implement dual factor authentication on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-authentication, winlogon, credential-providers

Once a user logs on to Windows with their normal credentials, I would like to communicate with a server, have that server send a push notification to my phone and complete the Windows login process by confirming that it's me on my phone. I'm currently stuck on getting Windows to send a notification to my server upon entering correct credentials in Windows Logon.

I've read pretty much every piece of documentation on the subject but I still don't have the answer. First, I learned about Credential Providers but I don't believe this is something to be done with cred providers since cred providers are only visible up to a successful local windows login. I would like to be able to stop the logon even if the user is able to login successfully with their local credentials. I believe the cred provider API does not allow this.

I've looked into implementing a subauthentication package, however they don't appear to work for interactive logins. I've looked into Winlogon notification events, however they don't seem to be supported beyond a certain Windows version.

I've read that it might be possible to use a Network Provider for this but I can't find any documentation or examples on the specifics of doing so.

I know this is possible because Duo Security has done it and I would like to make my own. Does anyone have any guidance on how I can proceed? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want a Credential Provider.  You just need to design it so that it requires the user to provide *both* a username and password *and* to pass the secondary test before it tells Windows to log the user in.

Comment: I would like it to pass Windows authentication before messaging my server though. I don't think that's possible with CPs...

Comment: I don't see what would stop you.  ... I'm not particularly familiar with the technology.  But once you've got the username and password, why not just call LogonUser to validate them?  ... You might find [pGina](http://pgina.org/index.html) interesting, you should be able to use the [Local Machine Plugin](http://pgina.org/docs/v3.0/local_machine.html) at the [Authentication stage](https://github.com/pgina/pgina/wiki/How-pGina-Works) and write your own plugin as an additional step for the Authorization stage.

Comment: I stuck with the same problem. Could you tell me how to get some event once windows default auth is successful? (in CP or another way). So that I can show my second-factor auth.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean two-factor authentication with SMS-code or you are planing to write a mobile application that confirms your identity?